# Count the number of real number pair $(X; Y)$ such that $A.X+B.Y$ and $C.X+D.Y$ are integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:** Given 4 positive integers $A,B,C,D (0<A,B,C,D<10^9)$. Count the number of real number pair $(X; Y)$ $(0 <X,\, Y<1)$ so that $A.X+B.Y$ and $C.X+D.Y$ are integers.

> For example, if $(A,B,C,D)=(1,2,10,12)$ 
>  There are 6 pairs $(X;Y):
>  (0.25,0.375),(0.5,0.25),(0.75,0.125),(0.25,0.875),(0.5,0.75),(0.75,0.625)$

This is my naitive approach.

> Clearly, $C.(A.X+B.Y)$ and $A.(C.X+D.Y)$ are integers. So $C.(A.X+B.Y)
>  - A.(C.X+D.Y) = Y.(BC - AD)$ is an integer.
>
> Similar, $(BC - AD).X$ is an integer.
>
> So, we check all pair $(X;Y)$ and $X, Y \in \Big\{\frac{1}{\mid BC-AD\mid},  \frac{2}{\mid BC-AD\mid}, ..., \frac{\mid BC-AD\mid-1}{\mid BC-AD\mid}\Big\}$

But now I have no effiecient approach, which solve the problem in $1$s. Please help me.

Comment: @lulu Sorry for my bad English, I have clarify that.

Comment: I don't see how you clarified anything.  You can't "check" each item on an infinite list, let alone an uncountable one.  Not really sure what you are after here.

Comment: I suggest working an example. I gave you an example where the answer was "uncountably many" but a different example might well give a finite list.  Try $(A,B,C,D)=(1,2,3,4)$ for instance.

Comment: Assume, $BC \neq AD$, I think $\Big\{\frac{1}{\mid BC-AD\mid},  \frac{2}{\mid BC-AD\mid}, ..., \frac{\mid BC-AD\mid-1}{\mid BC-AD\mid}\Big\}$ is an finite set

Comment: Ok, so if that's a condition, please add it to your question.  And why not check it with an example?  Presumably, one example will be rather like another...maybe the pattern will become clear.

Comment: Yes, they are all

Comment: As I proved, $Y.(BC - AD)$ is an integer and $0 < Y.(BC - AD) < BC-AD)$. In the given example, $8\times Y$ is an integer.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to recast this as a matrix problem.  if $Ax+By=n$ and $Cx+Dy=m$ then we know that $n<A+B$ and $m<C+D$ and we can rewrite this system as the matrix equation $M(x,y)=(n,m)$.  Now you just need to solve for $(x,y)$ given the possible $(n,m)$.

Comment: Personally, I experimented by setting $A,B,C,D = 3,5,7,11$ respectively.  Then I noticed that if $$(x,y) = \left(\frac{3 - \sqrt{2}}{3}, ~\frac{\sqrt{2}}{5}\right)$$ that although $(3x + 5y) \in \Bbb{Z},~$ that $(7x + 11y) \not\in \Bbb{Z}.$  That was as far as my thinking took me.  Then, I gave up, because it seemed that I was trying to *re-invent* *the wheel*, where someone with a greater knowledge of Field Theory and/or Number Theory could attack the problem much more easily than I.

Answer (score 0):

As per lulu's hint, let $$Ax + By = n\\Cx + Dy = m$$
This can be rewritten in terms of matrices:
$$\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}n\\m\end{bmatrix}$$
Call $M =\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}$. The determinant of $M$ is $$\det M = AD - BC$$
$M$ is invertible if and only if $\det M \ne 0$, in which case the inverse is
$$M^{-1}=\frac1{\det M}\begin{bmatrix}D&-B\\-C&A\end{bmatrix}$$
In this case we get $$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = M^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}n\\m\end{bmatrix} = \frac1{\det M}\begin{bmatrix}Dn - Bm\\Am - Cn\end{bmatrix}$$

So when $\det M \ne 0$, *every pair of integers $n, m$ gives a unique pair of real numbers $x, y$*. I.e., there are as many solutions $(x,y)$ as there are elements of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$.

But what happens when $\det M = 0$? Then $AD = BC$. If you multiply the top equation by $C$ and the bottom equation by $A$, and take the difference you get
$$(AD - BC)y = Am - Cn$$
And by a similar elimination of $y$, you get
$$(AD - BC)x = Dn - Bm$$
But $AD - BC  = 0$, so this only holds when $Am = Cn, Bm = Dn$, but because $AD = BC$, if $m, n$ satisfy one of those equation, they will also satisfy the other. Fir example, $m = D, n = B$ will work. But then, you can choose an arbitrary value for $y$ and calculate $$x = \frac BA(1-y) = \frac CD(1-y)$$ to get a corresponding $x$ making $Ax + By = B, Cx + Dy = D$.

Thus when $\det M = 0$, for some $(n, m)$ there are as many solutions for $(x,y)$ as there are real numbers.

Comment: Of course there are infinitely many solutions (all integers $X, Y$). But we need to find all $X, Y \in (0;1)$

Comment: @MinhHien - Your question says to *count* the solutions, not list them. If you wanted to *find* all solutions, that is what you should have asked! But I see I did forget that $x,y \in (0,1)$.